# Why do you put bootstrap classes into a div?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpwM3.jpg)

Why can't I put the class="col-xs-4" to the button's class?
It's stupid to not do that and will require extra typing for single elements.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code.  [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40224913/edit) the text into your question using the {} code tags.

Comment: Is this a legitimate question, because the way it comes across, it sounds more like a rant. Consider editing your question and put the code that you reference into your question instead of using a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason Bootstrap and most other frameworks like it use divs as their styling wrappers is because they're non-semantic, purely presentational elements. They're purely containers - whereas something like a button is actual page content. The mindset goes: leave the grid-sizing and layout to the containers, and then just let your actual content *fill* those containers. Think of them as different layers of concern - `col-xs-4` is just a box to put something in.

Answer (score 0):

Button is not a column.

It goes something like this;

```
<main class="container">
<section class="row">
<article class="col-lg-8">

</article>
<aside class="col-lg-4">

</aside>
</section>
</main>
```

Comment: What does it have to do with being a column?

Comment: If you look at the class css you will see that if you apply the styles of the columns and the class of the buttons to the button element then you will have one crazy deranged beast from mordor that you just don't want.

Comment: @Selsku you have no idea what bootstrap does. Go study the library